# Why does this nodejs proxy server hang?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, jsonp, script-tag

In browser javascript is pathetically broken in that the only way to make requests is using script tags and jsonp.  To make this useful, I'm trying to make a nodejs server that, given a callback name and address, loads the page at the address and pads it in a call to callback and serves the result.  However, I know next to nothing about nodejs.  If the server's response is loaded from a script tag it would result in actually loading a web page.  Currently, I'm writing the request as `localhost:8000/callback/address` so a script tag might be `<script src="localhost:8000/alert/https://www.google.com" type="text/javascript"></script>`.  Here is my code for the server:

```
var http = require("http");
var request = require("request");
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    req.on("end", function(){
        console.log("alive");
        var url = req.url;
        var i = url.indexOf("/", 1);
        request(url.substring(i + 1), function(err, ret, body){
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.write(url.substring(1, i) + "(\"" + body + "\");");
            res.end();
        });
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Why does this stay loading for a very long time but never actually load?  By using console.log() it seems as if the req.on("end") callback is never even called.

Comment: does `console.log('alive)'` gets printed?

Comment: can you try putting the log above `req.on("end", function(){` and making a request?

Comment: The server is listening, so hasn't the passed in 'req' already ended?

Comment: Note that to make this code work one should change body to body.replace(/[\\"\n]/g, "\\$&") and use "http://localhost:8000/callback/address" as the script address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about any request data, you could just add `req.resume();` after you add your `end` event handler.

The reason it's getting "stuck" is that since node v0.10, streams start out in a paused state, so you need to unpause them by reading from them in some way. `req.resume();` accomplishes this. Once there is nothing left in the request stream (which there could be nothing), the `end` event will be emitted.